# Boolean simplification expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

In words my problem is

NOT(p AND q) AND (NOT p OR q) AND (p OR p).

I have rewritten it in symbols

¬(p ∧ q) ∧ (¬p ∨ q) ∧ (p ∨ p)

I got this far:

(¬p ∨ ¬q) ∧(¬p ∨ q) ∧ p

Any help please?

Comment: You should get the null set.

Answer (score 1):

You can use De Morgan's law to start off with

$$\neg( (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge \neg q) \vee \neg p)$$

Then you can combine the first and second terms as $(p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge \neg q) = p$. See below for the intuition beind this: $(p \wedge q)$ in red, and $ (p \wedge \neg q) = p$ in green.

[image]

You should be good to go from there on in.

---

Alternatively, without the need for any intutition, it's possible to simply follow the [rules](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/#booleantheorems) of Boolean algebra. First of all you multiply out the brackets using the [distributive law](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/#distributivelaw).

$$\begin{align}
(\neg p \vee \neg q) \wedge (\neg p \vee q) \wedge p
&= (\neg p \vee \neg q) \wedge (\neg p \wedge p \;\vee\; q \wedge p) \\
&= (\neg p \vee \neg q) \wedge (q \wedge p) \\
&= \neg p \wedge q \wedge p \;\;\vee\;\; \neg q \wedge q \wedge p
\end{align}$$

Second you use the [associative law](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/Labview/boolalgebra/#associatelaw) to rearrange the logical AND on the left to $\neg p \wedge p \wedge q$.

Comment: Ahh! Got it! it becomes p ∧ (q ∨ ¬q)!

Comment: @user128891 yes, exactly. I'd started a drawing when I saw your comment and I've added that to my answer.

Comment: @user128891 what you wrote prompted me to do some leg work and look up the formal rules of Boolean algebra. I've added a second approach and some links which you might find useful (I did).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** 
Using De Morgan's law, your last step is: [(~p v (~q and q) ) and p].